# Using Ember's {{link-to}} in jQuery plugin

Tags: ember.js

I have an Ember application that uses a jQuery plugin, and the jQuery plugin renders a link. Is there anyway to use Ember's link-to helper to render the link so that the page will not refresh?

Comment: No this is not possible. What does the plugin do that you really have to use it? Sounds weird. Maybe you write a custom View that uses the jQuery plugin. This way around it could work.

Comment: It is the fullCalendar jQuery plugin. I am using a view to render the calendar, however the calendar renders the link to the "detailed event view" and I was wondering if that link can be rendered using {{link-to}}

Comment: You mean clicking on an event? Having a short look at http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/ , i think you should use the eventClick callback to integrate with Ember.

Comment: Here's someone's working Ember + fullcalendar integration: http://jsfiddle.net/uMVyu/1/

Comment: This is sort of like asking how you can use your toaster in your car.

Comment: @torazaburo I don't think it is. Ember uses jQuery underneath, so it is not unheard of to preserve the "feel" of a single page app but using Ember's link-to helper or transitions as suggested above....

PS: To use toaster in a car, get a 12v to 110v converter.